# Sitemap Routing in Symfony 6

Tags: symfony6, sitemap.xml

I want to make a sitemap in symfony 6 but I don't know how to do the routing.

```
symfony 5.
 /**
     * @Route("/sitemap.xml", name="sitemap", **defaults={"_format"="xml"**})
     */

Symfony 6.
  #[Route('/sitemap', name: 'app_sitemap', ?...)]
```

thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Route class has various parameters to the constructor, such as `default: ['_format' => 'xml']`.

The https://github.com/prestaconcept/PrestaSitemapBundle May also greatly assist.

Comment: the s is missing "defaults" , but the rest is correct. thank you